# Method Not Found Exception in thread C#

Tags: winforms, exception, pthreads

this is baffling me, I would appreciate some help. I have a thread that loads databases from a server in the background into a custom control that I've created.

The thread retrieves the databases just fine, but when I try to access **some** methods in my custom control i get thrown that exception and I don't know why!!

here's my code:

```
{
        DatabaseLoader = new Thread(()=> AquireDatabases(LoginInfo));
        DatabaseLoader.Name = "DatabaseLoader";
        DatabaseLoader.IsBackground = true;
        DatabaseLoader.Start();
}

    private void AquireDatabases(List<Object> loginInfo)
    {
        DataTable dtDatabases = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            dtDatabases = objBkp.FillCBDatabases(loginInfo[0].ToString(), loginInfo[1].ToString(), loginInfo[2].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        LoadDatabasesinControl(dtDatabases, null);
    }

    private void LoadDatabasesinControl(DataTable dtDatabases, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new WorkerCompleteDelegate(LoadDatabasesinControl), dtDatabases, e);
            return;
        }

        if (DatabaseLoader.IsAlive || !(DatabaseLoader.ThreadState == ThreadState.AbortRequested))
        {
            // CLEAR ALL ITEMS IN the control before filling it
            serverControl.ClearControl();  // --> EXCEPTION THROWN

            for (int i = 0; i < dtDatabases.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                serverControl.CreateDatabase();
                serverControl.DatabaseName = dtDatabases.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                serverControl.lblSubDBSize = 150513; // --> EXCEPTION THROWN
            }
        }
    }
```

method ClearControl() is a public method in my control, and it returns type void just like CreateDatabase()
also, lblSubDBSize is a regular public label just like DatabaseName!

Why is the exception being thrown on these two only, and none of the other functions I try to access???
I think this is a thread problem but I don't know what it is exactly.
I added my custom control as an existing project and I added the reference to it as a project to my solution instead of as a dll. I read somewhere that that could be that cause but it wasn't, I tried a bunch of stuff with no luck.

Any thoughts anyone???

**[EDIT]**

serverControl is a custom User Control

```
    public Database database;
    private Label lblServer;
    private Button btnServerPanelExpander;
    private Panel pnlServerHeader;
    private List<Database> databaseCollection = new List<Database>();

    public ServerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ControlInitializer();
    }

    private void ControlInitializer()
    {
        lblServer = new Label();
        pnlServerHeader = new Panel();
        btnServerPanelExpander = new Button();
        btnServerPanelExpander.Click += btnServerPanelExpander_Click;

        pnlServerHeader.Controls.Add(btnServerPanelExpander);
        pnlServerHeader.Controls.Add(lblServer);

        pnlServer.Controls.Add(pnlServerHeader);
        setProperties();
    }

    public void ClearControl()
    {
        if (database == null)
            return;

        this.pnlServer.Controls.Clear();
        this.ControlInitializer();
        this.pnlServer.Invalidate();
    }

    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        database = new Database();
        database.SetIcon(DatabaseIcon);

        databaseCollection.Add(database);
        pnlServer.Controls.Add(database.pnlDatabase);

        DrawDatabase(database);
    }
```

and here is the stack trace and exception... hope this clarifies things

**Exception Message**
"Method not found: 'Void ServersControl.ServerControl.ClearControl()'."

**Stack Trace**
"   at Forms.MainSmall.LoadDatabasesinControl(DataTable dtDatabases, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)\r\n   at Forms.MainSmall.AquireDatabases(List`1 loginInfo)\r\n   at Forms.MainSmall.b__1370_0()\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"

Comment: 1- Your codes are incomplete, for example we don't know what the type `serverControl` is. 2- Post exception message completely. (Also  stacktrace may be useful)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've included some addition info, hope this helps